# Remove extra space , number, characters from start and end of the string

Tags: oracle

Need to remove extra space , number, characters from start and end of the string

```
Column 1
11 2013US83838
2019IN353535 2


Output
2013US83838
2019IN353535
```

Comment: How many characters after/in front of the space mean "extra characters"? For example, why shouldn't the second output be just "2" (similarly to the first output, which is a string that follows the space - "2013US83838"). Or vice versa?

Comment: I want the output in a same way which is mentioned in question. Is it possible we can get that output using regexp.

Comment: OK, but which rule(s) should be followed? I can *see* what you mean, but - how to write a query which will do that? Why should I remove "11" in the first example and "2" in the second? Why isn't the result "11 and 2019IN353535" or "2013US83838 and 2"?

Comment: Because 11 and 2 are like junk data that needs to be removed.

Comment: As I said: it is *obvious* when I look at data you posted, but why are 11 and 2 junk? How can query know that 11 is junk and 2013US83838 is not junk?

Comment: Rather than focusing on what to remove, can you explain what you want to keep instead? It looks like you might want to extract a pattern with four digits followed by two characters followed by some more digits. Even if that is the case, can that pattern appear more than once, and what happens if so? You need to be able to explain the rules/logic for how to manipulate the raw data in plain language (in the question, not just in comments!) before that can be translated to code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your desired format has 4 digits (year?) then 2 upper-case letters (country code?) and then a 5-or-more digit number then you can use:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
         column1,
         '^(.* )?(\d{4}[A-Z]{2}\d{5,})( .*)?$',
         '\2'
       ) AS output
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (Column1) AS
SELECT '11 2013US83838' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2019IN353535 2' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| OUTPUT |
| --- |
| 2013US83838 |
| 2019IN353535 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KGtaxrpe)

Answer (score 0):

This will return the *longest* substring from the column. I have no idea whether that's what you want or not because discussion (in comments) didn't help much.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '11 2013US83838' from dual union all
  3     select '2019IN353535 2' from dual
  4    ),
```

Split values into rows, separated by space character. Rank substrings by their length:

```
  5  temp as
  6    (select col,
  7       regexp_substr(col, '[^ ]+', 1, column_value) val,
  8       length(regexp_substr(col, '[^ ]+', 1, column_value)) len,
  9       rank() over (partition by col order by length(regexp_substr(col, '[^ ]+', 1, column_value)) desc) rnk
 10     from test cross join
 11       table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 12                           connect by level <= regexp_count(col, ' ') + 1
 13                          ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 14    )
```

Finally, fetch values that ranked as *the highest* (`val` is desired output):

```
 15  select col, val
 16  from temp
 17  where rnk = 1;

COL            VAL
-------------- --------------
11 2013US83838 2013US83838
2019IN353535 2 2019IN353535

SQL>
```